# Click through a VBA Userform

Tags: vba, excel, solidworks

Was just wondering if its possible to click through a userform.

Background is the following:

I made a userform where the user needs to select sketches. When the user starts selecting, the userform is going transparent. Is it possible to make this userform now unclickable, so I can select sketches and features beneath the userform?

Answer (score 0):

You can either hide the userform or launch it in non-modal state in the first place:

```
userformName.Show Modal:=False
```

But then you need to be careful with your code because any code after this line will run immediately. You also need to close your form in code.

Comment: thats not what i meant. In Excel for example, lets say you have a userform. This form is now transparent and you want to select a cell thats beneath this userform. You can only see it because the form is transparent.

Comment: Hi, Would you mind sharing the 'Transparent Form' Code you have ? I happen to have a code making a form transparent AND clic-through... And i want it not Form-unclickable.